# Starting Sentences

Tags: creative-writing, screenwriting, sentence-structure

I have been working on a book on an online website lately and while I was looking through my previous chapters I find myself starting sentences repeatedly with the character's pronoun or name. I want to get rid of that habit, but I am struggling to find new ways to start a sentence.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I steer myself away from using pronouns too often as I write in 3rd person?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/50312/how-can-i-steer-myself-away-from-using-pronouns-too-often-as-i-write-in-3rd-pers)